# AlertConfig Cancel Button

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am using the following alert in the mvvmcross, I wonder how could I able to add a cancel button.

```
var alertConfig = new AlertConfig {
    Message = "it is not valid",
    OkText = "Okely",
    OnOk = () => { Debug.WriteLine("ok pressed"); }
};

Mvx.Resolve<IUserDialogs>().Alert(alertConfig);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use [Confirm](https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs/blob/master/docs/confirm.md) instead.  `Alert`, as the name implies, is to Alert the user to something, and the only action is to dismiss the `Alert`.

Comment: Could you please check the following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48757425/task-operation-on-datetime-object